# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not recognizing Nvidia 640M GPU after update. Having issues with Nvidia Driver

Tags: nvidia, kernel

Been having a problem with my Nvidia 640M not being recognized by Ubuntu after an update. Tried many things but couldn't find a solution yet. I'm relatively new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure where to look at.

I'd really appreciate help with this

Something I noticed on nvidia log:

```
echo >&2;                           
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  
echo >&2 ;                          
/bin/false)
```

Comment: have you looked at additional drivers under Software & updates ?? I had problems with driver-455 and changed back to 450. You can also try the open source driver version as you have a older machine and it may work fine with opensource.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Browse the Nvidia site to determine the exact driver for your card. note it: eg. nvidia driver 390.
2. Use synaptic or muon to change your graphics driver to the Nouveau driver.
3. Reboot
4. Issue this terminal command to purge nvidia drivers:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
   ```
5. Reboot
6. Open synaptic or muon. At top search box enter nvidia. search for your specific driver. you may find many entries. the one you want is the "nvidia meta" package.
7. Highlight your specific driver meta package and install it. Installation can take a long time.
8. Reboot. This should get nvidia working properly. You should be able also to invoke the nvidia settings GUI application.